# Addressing QTableWidget Columns

Tags: c++, qt, input, widget, qtablewidget

I am a student programmer and have been building a GUI in Qt for my company. I am writing a member function SetData to basically act as an intermediary between my Ui elements and member variables. In this particular Ui I am using a QTableWidge. I can't seem to find out exactly how to set each column to a variable.

For instance if I have the column Name in my QTableWidget, and Name is the first column I can't access it using the traditional array parameters. The [documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qtablewidget.html#insertRow) from Qt is really hazey as to how to address this.. It could also be that I am still too amateur to understand how to use the class's member functions to achieve the results I want here.

To clarify I am trying to define a data type for an entire column. For instance my first column; Name, would be a variable that I have created which is a QString data type. and SetData would pass it to eventually a QVector or QList. Here is the code I have typed up so far to kinda give an Idea of what I thought I could do.

```
 void InjectionDialog::setData(InjectionData &setDataStruct)
    {
        /*The following setData functions assists in creating a new instance of
          the Injection dialog with whatever values are passed to setDataStruct*/
        QString str;//created str to make datatype conversion
        ui->lineEditFluidVelocity->setText(str.setNum(setDataStruct.lineEditFluidVelocity));
        ui->lineEditFluidMassFlow->setText(str.setNum(setDataStruct.lineEditFluidMassFlow));
    ui->lineEditFluidArea->setText(str.setNum(setDataStruct.lineEditFluidArea));
        ui->lineEditFluidTemperature->setText(str.setNum(setDataStruct.lineEditFluidTemperture));
        ui->lineEditFluidPressure->setText(str.setNum(setDataStruct.lineEditPressure));
        ui->lineEditParticleManual->setText(str.setNum(setDataStruct.lineEditManualParticlesPerCell));
        ui->lineEditParticleVelocity->setText(str.setNum(setDataStruct.lineEditParitcleVelocity));
        ui->lineEditParticleMassFlow->setText(str.setNum(setDataStruct.lineEditParticleMassFlow));
        ui->lineEditParticleArea->setText(str.setNum(setDataStruct.lineEditParticleArea));
        ui->lineEditParticleTemperature->setText(str.setNum(setDataStruct.lineEditParticleTemperture));
        ui->tableWidgetInjectionLocations //this is where I got stuck
}
```

I know that QTreeView has the option to set items by delegating columns but I need these fields to be able to be edited. I could be going about this all wrong in handling my QTableWidget; if so I appreciate any advice in how to appropriately handle this Widget.

Comment: QTableWidgetItem *newItem = new QTableWidgetItem(tr("%1").arg(
         (row+1)*(column+1)));
     tableWidget->setItem(row, column, newItem);

Is there anything that this piece of code from that document cannot do for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research and trial and error through QTableWidgetItem; I found what I was looking for. As I said earlier I needed to write a setData function to provide a way to set each cell to some specified data using QTableWidget. [QTableWidget](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/QTableWidget.html) uses [setItem](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qtablewidget.html#setItem) to set each item to a [QTableWidgetItem](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qtablewidgetitem.html). Knowing this I just filled in the purpose. Here's what I did; This is right after my main code.

```
for(int i=0; i<setDataStruct.qTableWidegetlocations.size(); i++)
            {
                QTableWidgetItem *qTableWidgetItemInjectionName = new QTableWidgetItem(setDataStruct.qTableWidegetlocations[i].locationsInjectionName);
                ui->tableWidgetInjectionLocations->setItem(i,0, qTableWidgetItemInjectionName);
                QTableWidgetItem *qTableWidgetItemInjectionOnOff= new QTableWidgetItem((setDataStruct.qTableWidegetlocations[i].locationsInjectionOnOff));
                ui->tableWidgetInjectionLocations->setItem(i,1, qTableWidgetItemInjectionOnOff);
                QTableWidgetItem *qTableWidgetItemInjectionX = new QTableWidgetItem(setDataStruct.qTableWidegetlocations[i].locationsX);
                ui->tableWidgetInjectionLocations->setItem(i,2, qTableWidgetItemInjectionX);
                QTableWidgetItem *qTableWidgetItemInjectionY = new QTableWidgetItem(setDataStruct.qTableWidegetlocations[i].locationsY);
                ui->tableWidgetInjectionLocations->setItem(i,3, qTableWidgetItemInjectionY);
                QTableWidgetItem *qTableWidgetItemInjectionZ = new QTableWidgetItem(setDataStruct.qTableWidegetlocations[i].locationsZ);
                ui->tableWidgetInjectionLocations->setItem(i,4,qTableWidgetItemInjectionZ);
                QTableWidgetItem *qTableWidgetItemInjectionnx = new QTableWidgetItem(setDataStruct.qTableWidegetlocations[i].locationsnx);
                ui->tableWidgetInjectionLocations->setItem(i,5,qTableWidgetItemInjectionnx);
                QTableWidgetItem *qTableWidgetItemInjectionny = new QTableWidgetItem(setDataStruct.qTableWidegetlocations[i].locationsny);
                ui->tableWidgetInjectionLocations->setItem(i,6,qTableWidgetItemInjectionny);
                QTableWidgetItem *qTableWidgetItemInjectionnz = new QTableWidgetItem(setDataStruct.qTableWidegetlocations[i].locationsnz);
                ui->tableWidgetInjectionLocations->setItem(i,7,qTableWidgetItemInjectionnz);
                QTableWidgetItem *qTableWidgetItemInjectionTemperature = new QTableWidgetItem(setDataStruct.qTableWidegetlocations[i].locationsTemperature);
                ui->tableWidgetInjectionLocations->setItem(i,8,qTableWidgetItemInjectionTemperature);
                QTableWidgetItem *qTableWidgetItemInjectionWeight = new QTableWidgetItem(setDataStruct.qTableWidegetlocations[i].locationsWeight);
        }
```

Thanks For Reading